# APScheduler to do jop every day withon 11:15am to 2:15 pm on 15 min delay

Tags: python, apscheduler

I need to do a job with 15 mins interval within 11:15 am to 2:15 pm IST every day,
I tried using the below code but still i cannot able to get it.
Any answers would be really appreciated.

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler,BlockingScheduler

from datetime import datetime

```
def my_job():
   print(f"custom job called at {datetime.now()}")
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(my_job, 'cron', minute='1', hour='12-14')
scheduler.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

trigger = OrTrigger([CronTrigger(hour='11', minute='15-59/15'),
                     CronTrigger(hour='12-13', minute='0-59/15'),
                     CronTrigger(hour='14', minute='0-15/15')])
scheduler.add_job(my_job, trigger,timezone='Asia/Kolkata')
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: This answer looks very similar to mine, posted 7 hours before yours... Also this will not work, because the add_job function doesn't take a timezone argument. If you want to configure the timezone, pass the argument to the `BlockingScheduler` class with `BlockingScheduler(timezone="Asia/Kolkata")`

Comment: It works, I tried it before posting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I see to achieve those times would be to create multiple triggers with the [`OrTrigger`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/combining.html#apscheduler.triggers.combining.OrTrigger). I also used different [cron operators](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/triggers/cron.html#expression-types), to make it run every 15 minutes.

```py
from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger

trigger = OrTrigger([CronTrigger(hour='11', minute='15-59/15'),
                     CronTrigger(hour='12-13', minute='0-59/15'),
                     CronTrigger(hour='14', minute='0-15/15')])
scheduler.add_job(my_job, trigger)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Ethansocal, and will this work for IST or should I change the timezone manually

Comment: @SANJAY.R This will work off of the system clock, so as long as your computer's clock is in IST, it should work.